# React: passing in properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass in store as a property to AddTodo but I am getting the error: Cannot read property 'todos' of undefined

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'

const todo = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            return {
                id: action.id,
                text: action.text
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

const todos = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            return [
                ...state,
                todo(undefined, action)
            ];
        default:
            return state
    }
}

let store = createStore(todos)


let nextTodoId = 0
const AddTodo = () => {
    let input;

    //this works
    console.log(store.getState())
    //this doesn't
    console.log(this.props.todos)


    return (
        <div>
            <input ref={node => {input = node}}/>
            <button onClick = {() => {
                store.dispatch({
                    type: 'ADD_TODO',
                    id: nextTodoId++,
                    text: input.value
                });
                input.value = ''
            }}>
                Add Todo
            </button>



        </div>
    )
};

store.subscribe(AddTodo)


ReactDOM.render(
    <AddTodo 
        todos={store.getState()}
    />,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

I am a little confused why I am getting the error when printing `this.props.todos`. I thought I was passing in `todos` as a prop in `<AddTodo todos={...}/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functional components work differently, they don't have a context of `this`, but their props are passed through the arguments of the function

To make it work, just change your function call of addToDos, like this:

```
const AddTodo = (props) => {
  let input;
  console.log(props.todos);
  return (/* and the rest of your code...*/) ;
};
```

For the rest, as Arun Ghosh is saying, you should revisit your subscribe pattern, for example like this

```
store.subscribe(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <AddTodo 
           todos={store.getState()}
        />,
        document.getElementById('root'));
});
```

Comment: In the redux tutorial, he `uses this.props.todos` - http://imgur.com/a/7y4ig What am I doing differently?

Comment: Is he not using components? You are using functional components

Comment: ahh ok. Got it. let me try to get this to work. Thanks. I forgot that is the difference between const vs component

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the store object and subscribe for changes

```
store.subscribe(() => {
  // In our case the state will be updated when todos are set
  console.log(store.getState().todos);
});
```