# Passing an object as prop in React-router Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm getting the list of products in `ProductList`, in which, I need to pass the selected product object to `Product`.

Currently, I'm trying pass the `id` as a route param and get the product object again. But I want to send the entire product object from `ProductList` to `Product`.

My Route is

```
<Route path={joinPath(["/product", ":id?"])} component={Product} />
```

ProductList component Link

```
<Link to={"/product/" + this.props.product.Id} >{this.props.product.Name} </Link>
```

How to pass product object to `Product` as a prop?

the below one throws error in Typescript saying the following property does not exist on `Link` Type.

```
<Link to={"/product/" + this.props.product.Id} params={product}>{Name}</Link>
```

I tried the following questions, but none seems to have my issues.

- [Pass props in Link react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115324/pass-props-in-link-react-router#30115524)
  `<--- this is similar to my issue, but answer doesn't work for react-router v4`
- [react-router - pass props to handler component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864720/react-router-pass-props-to-handler-component)
- [React: passing in properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44748547/react-passing-in-properties)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "`to`" property of `Link` can accept an object so you can pass your props like this :

```
<Link to={
    { 
        pathname: "/product/" + this.props.product.Id,
        myCustomProps: product
    }
}>
    {Name}
</Link>
```

Then you should be able to access them in `this.props.location.myCustomProps`

Comment: Yes, I was able to do it the same way now. Although I think getting from `redux` would be neater.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `redux` for retrieving the data. When you navigate to product route you can get the `product` details by dispatching some action.

```
componentDidMount() {
    let productId = this.props.match.params.Id;
    this.props.actions.getProduct(productId);
}
```

The `product` route should be connected with the the store.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Yea, was thinking about the same. But is it possible to pass an object as prop to another component tru `Link`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it through query params as in [Pass object through Link in react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168014/pass-object-through-link-in-react-router), which is quite ugly.

Also you can try to replace Link with some other element, e.g. button and in click listener do location change via `browserHistory.push({ pathname:"/product/" + this.props.product.Id, state: this.props.product})` and and product as `state` property.

Comment: `browserHistory` is not there in `React-router-v4`

Comment: Yes, now it is a separate module, you need to include it https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router