# How to use Route in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I need some guidance on the `reactjs` `Routes` and how to manifest them properly.

So I have my react directory as below (I will omit unnecessary directories and files)

```
Routes.js
App.js
src/
   ComponentOne.jsx
   ComponentTwo.jsx
```

My curent `Routes.js` looks like this

```
import ComponentOne from './src/ComponentOne'
import ComponentTwo from './src/ComponentTwo'

<Route path='/banuka/' exact component={ComponentOne} />
<Route path='/banuka/test' exact component={ComponentTwo} />
```

And in the `ComponentOne.jsx` there is a nothing but a button wrapped in a `Link` of `react-router-dom`

```
let valueobject = {<some-key-value-pairs>} // take a note on this line

<Link to={`/banuka/test`}>
    <Button variant="dark">    
    Upload Data
    </Button>
</Link>
```

So when I click on this `Button` it navigates me two `ComponentTwo` component.

This is where the problem comes in:

**I want to pass the variable `valueobject` which is an object conains key-value pairs as `props` from `ComponentOne` to `ComponentTwo`**

But as you can see, the `ComponentTwo` is already being rendered in the `Routes.js`

How can I achieve this?

You can suggest me a better way (even if it means, I have to delete the `Routes.js`, but it is better if I can keep it as is) to achieve this, so it will look like:

```
<ComponentTwo values={valueobject}/>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I see three, in my opinion preferred ways to realize this: 1.) Use global state management, like Redux, MobX etc. and let the component two get the data from the store. 2.) Try to represent the state via url. Which would mean the route would be something like this: `/banuka/test/:someId/:someMoreInfo` and you would redirect based on a button press towards: `/banuka/test/42/bananas`, there is already such a solution provided: 3.) https://stackoverflow.com/a/48949836/3977134

Comment: Look at using the Link to send some route state: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object

Comment: @r3dst0rm I liked your approach but how can I send a data object like this with the query parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send as route state

https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link

```
let valueobject = {<some-key-value-pairs>} // take a note on this line

<Link
  to={{
    pathname: '/banuka/test',
    state: {
      ...valueobject,
    },
  }}
>
    <Button variant="dark">    
    Upload Data
    </Button>
</Link>
```

Comment: Thank you, may I ask why you have put three dots here?

Comment: @user13456401 Ah yes, this is the spread syntax, to spread all the key-value pairs of `valueobject` into the route state object. So for example if `valueobject = { foo: 'a', bar: 13 }`, then the route state can be accessed as such `location.state.foo // a` and `location.state.bar // 13`.

Comment: How can I pass a normal value (a string) with this method? how the syntax looks like?

Comment: @user13456401 `to={{ pathname: "...", state: 'foobar' }}` or `to={{ pathname: "...", state: { foo: 'bar' } }}`, it's the object form so state is *just* a key to *some* value, it can be a primitive or object.

Comment: Thank you I get this, but I still have the problem on how this syntax works. What if I had two variables (not an object), how can I pass them using this syntax? and how can I access this from the other component?

Comment: @user13456401 It's not special syntax, it's just an object literal. Few options: Object Shorthand `to={{ pathname: "...", state: { var1, var2, var3 } }}` here the keys will be the same as the variable names, or normal object notation `to={{ pathname: "...", state: { key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: value3} }}`. The former could be accessed `location.state.var3`, the latter `location.state.key2`. *Anything* you want to sent in route state should be packed into the `state` property of the `to` object.